# how to show result of java program in console output in eclipse using log4j logger?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

i am trying to write a program with jena library for my ontology. 
For jena i am using log4j when i add jena libraries to my project, eclipse console do not show any result but without it `System.out.println("something")` works good. i think problem is in log4j. and to set console output to it.but i don't know how to use this. 
this is my code:

```
package tutorial;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.*;

import java.io.*;
public class helloRDFworld {

    private InfModel model;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        helloRDFworld  application=new  helloRDFworld();
        application.test();
    }

    private void loadantology (String antologyfile)
    {
        try {
            String uri =new File(antologyfile).toURI().toString();
            model.read(uri);
            } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public helloRDFworld(){
        model=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
    }
    public void test()
    {
        loadantology("food.owl");

    }

}
```

this is my library list 
[image]
[image]

share your information please

with Regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a log4j.properties file and add it to your classpath. Add this to your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, Console
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Make sure you have your apache log4j library.

Then declare and initialise like this:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(classname.class);
```

Then use it to capture errors, debug or info messages e.g.

```
logger.info("This is info ");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i have an error using this code .getlogger input argument must be a string

Comment: Which library are you using? I always use apache, I am guessing you are importing java.util which takes string as argument.

Comment: Do you have your log4j.properties file in your class path?

Comment: i don't have it in my project folder but in my library path i have it.

Comment: I have edited my answer and have added steps. I followed those steps and seems to work for me. Also I would recommend reading this: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html